# Bluetooth card pairing better

Tags: bluetooth

Is there a chance that a Bluetooth card might pair better with some wireless headphones?

I have had no luck with BT dongles. I have used 4 different brands.

I feel that I should be able to use BT wireless headphones.

The Altec Lansing headphones pair quite well with my Samsung S5, so it reasonable to think that Ubuntu could do the same.

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

2/14/18

One dongle did not show in `lsusb`.

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)

Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0

Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

2/17/18

Maybe an exorcism? :-)

Comment: Can you give some more information about your question that relates it to Ubuntu?

Comment: What brand dongles have you used, can you edit the question to include the names and their entry from results of terminal command `lsusb` when each dongle is attached?

Comment: The 0a5c:21e8 device should work fine unless you want to use low quality HFP/HSP audio.  You could try pairing in terminal using `bluetoothctl` followed by `power on` and `scan on` then it should display the MAC address of the headphones if they are in pairing mode then do `pair` followed by the exact MAC address of the headphones

Comment: No luck. andyk_~/Downloads$ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 5C:F3:70:80:FF:DA k [default]
[NEW] Device 54:BD:79:1C:57:9D 54-BD-79-1C-57-9D
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 5C:F3:70:80:FF:DA Discovering: yes
[bluetooth]# pair 5C:F3:70:80:FF:DA
Device 5C:F3:70:80:FF:DA not available
[bluetooth]#

Comment: Can you pair the computer with the phone?  You should try the command `pair 54:BD:79:1C:57:9D` as that might be the headset and 5C:F3:70:80:FF:DA is actually the MAC of your bluetooth dongle

Comment: [bluetooth]# pair 54:BD:79:1C:57:9D
Attempting to pair with 54:BD:79:1C:57:9D
[bluetooth]#

Comment: What is the MAC address of the headset as reported by the Samsung S5?

Comment: [NEW] Device E4:F8:EF:B8:8B:08 SAMSUNG-SM-G900V